# Android Create Circle / ARC

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a UI element as given below
 [image]

This basically is an arc which is filled with a particular color(Here it is red). 
Based on the number the extent upto which the color is filled will change .
For example - when the number reaches 500 the whole arc will be filled with red color.

Can somebody suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try creating a UI element of your own. You have to create a subclass of View as explained in the doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html.
You'll have to extend/override (amongst other things) the onDraw method.

Comment: Yes i had to do it that way.